# vs code - комментарии кода

Tags: visual-studio-code

В редакторе `vs code` в конце файла с кодом имею группу своих комментариев, которые идут друг за другом, например, так:

```
/* По теме [A]
   ...
*/

/* По теме [B]
   ...
*/

/* По теме [C]
   ...
*/
```

В моём случае их более десятка, я их `сворачиваю` и файл сохраняю. После перезагрузки компа
и открытия файла первые четыре комментария получаю всегда развёрнутыми. Как сделать так, чтобы комментарии:

- 1. в том виде, как сохранил, - так и открывались
- 2. при открытии - все комменты были свёрнутыми?

Также по теме хотел узнать:

---

существует ли толковое решение привязки комментариев (документирования кода: назначения, вносимые изменения и т.д.), например, с хранением их в базе  данных и выводом, например, в браузер (локалхост), чтобы была возможность как привязки к коду текста и картинок, так и редактирования.

Comment: сохранение файла тут не причем, ибо в файле нет информации о свёрнутости комментариев

Comment: @Pavel Gridin, описал действия, чтобы показать, что часть комментариев, разворачивается, а часть нет. причину не понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тестировал под win_10 с файлами rust.
Если комментарий имеет вид, когда вторая строка имеет отступ, - то такой `коммент`, сохранённый свёрнутым, - разворачивает при перезагрузке:

```
/* По теме [A]
   текст комментария ...
*/
```

Так не разворачивает (остаётся свёрнутый):

```
/* По теме [A]
текст комментария ...
*/
```

`Коммент` оформленный так, тоже не разворачивает:

```
// По теме [A]
// текст комментария ...
```